# How can I set transactions mandatory for read operations in Quarkus?

Tags: transactions, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I recently discovered that I can perform read operations using a Panache repository during a `QuarkusTest` without an active transaction. This behavior took me by surprise, and it also resulted in incorrect data being returned (possibly due to caching). As soon as I put an active transaction around the test, everything works as expected. Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce the issue with a reproducer. I attempted to find a configuration option to enforce a transaction for read operations, but I was unable to locate a suitable setting.

How can I configure Quarkus with Hibernate ORM to make transactions mandatory, even for read operations?

It seems that setting the `TransactionRequirement` to `STRICT` is not a viable solution for me, as it would prevent the Liquibase migration from executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access a read-only entity manager / session outside of transactions. That's (very) questionable behavior in my opinion, but some people actually rely on that.

There is no built-in way to disable that as far as I know, but you can certainly [open an issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/new/choose) to suggest a configuration property.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll go that way then  https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34016